# Accessing and working with PowerShell objects in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have retrieved a PowerShell object using C# but am not 100% sure how I work with the received data. I have managed to access 1st level object properties as follows:

```
foreach (PSObject workflowName in workflowNames)
        {
            var pSMembers = workflowName.Members;
            metroTextBoxWfDescription.Text = pSMembers["Description"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

What if "Description" was another object and I wanted to access that sub object? In PowerShell it would be as easy as $psMembers.Description.Sub1.Sub2 etc. How can the same be achieved in C#?

In general if anyone has a good beginners guide to working with this type of data it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a pic of the object I have grabbed. Say I want to access DefaultAction -> Prompt -> AudioFilePrompt -> OriginalFileName, how would I do that? In PS its as simple as $workflowName.DefaultAction.Prompt.AudioFilePrompt.OriginalFileName, but similar doesnt seem to work in C#.

[image: PS Object]

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If you define the PowerShell object as type `dynamic` you just access the properties:

```
foreach (dynamic workflowName in workflowNames) 
{
    metroTextBoxWfDescription.Text = worflowName.Description;
}
```

Of course, you better be right about the property names as the compiler won't verify them on a dynamic type.

Comment: Hey Keith, Thanks for helping. That method appears to work to get the direct properties from the object, but how can I access the sub objects e.g. Description is a collection of objects and I want to target one of these sub objects - I tried worflowName.Description.Sub1 but it didnt work.

Comment: If Description is a collection then you would index it with either a number or string (typically) try `workflowName.Description[0]`

Comment: See the image in the edited post - maybe I am using the wrong terminology. I have a PowerShell background and am a C# beginner so please excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: `workflowName.DefaultAction.Prompt.AudioFilePrompt.OriginalFileName` should work.  Keep in mind that PowerShell doesn't care about the case of .NET properties.  However, I can't remember if dynamic in C# does. I believe it does so make sure the casing matches what you see in the C# data tip window.

Comment: Tired another example and it worked!! Thanks very much :) I'll figure out what was wrong with my previous example later.